# is it bad to use somename.local as domain?

Tags: dns

I have setup my home network with a couple of linux'es with webmin, isc-dhcp and bind9

I'm using "neland.local" as domain, for instance pi.neland.local or dell-mini.neland.local

It works from windows and linuxes, but from the raspberry it does not resolve.

```
# host mini.neland.local
mini.neland.local has address 192.168.1.254
# ping mini.neland.local
ping: mini.neland.local: Name or service not known
```

Is it avahi which is messing up **.local** domains?
Should I use another domain, like **neland.home** or **neland.lan**?

---

**UPDATE:** after changing to **neland.lan** things started working normally without "magic" domains messing up.

Comment: Paste in the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Is you question whether using ```local``` is bad in a home network, or whether you should be using ```local``` for a domain outside of mdns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While there's nothing wrong with using `.local` internally in your home, you probably do *not* want to use it for anything other than mdns as used by `avahi/bonjour` because of the conflict.

Bonjour uses `.local` and it is absolutely appropriate to use it in a home setting (i.e. from clients to refer to a device). I would not suggest using such a "well known" domain for your own internal dns services simply because of this inevitable conflict.

Comment: I changed my domain from neland.local to neland.lan, and things started working normally. It's frustrating when "magic" happens on stuff you think you understand.

Comment: There seems to have been some confusion in the industry about this as well. Internally, you can configure your dns however you like, so using something *besides* ```.local``` is your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with using domain .local for your home. In many situations  .local are often employed in private networks, where they are resolved either via the multicast domain name service (mDNS) or local Domain Name System (DNS) servers.  ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.local

In current times with SSO and such its been make known that connecting local .local domains to cloud based 'saas' apps may be problematic and should be avoiced when possible.   I started using .int (for internal)