# Local DNSMasq .local domain problem

Tags: raspbian, networking, pi-zero-w, dns

I have a problem with name resolution on one of my Pis. 
I have set my router to start `dnsmasq` with LAN domain `local`. Other systems except this Pi can ping `host.local` addresses just fine.

I installed `dnsutils` on my Pi to see if this is a DNSMasq problem. When I do `nslookup ipad.local`, I get the IP and the correct response. But when I do `ping ipad.local`, the name doesn't get resolved. However, to my surprise, when I change it omitting .local, it works: `ping ipad` How can I make the .local domain get resolved?

Comment: Hmmm: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/78014/5538

Answer (score 1):

Turn out I had to change priorities in /etc/nsswitch.conf from:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

to

```
hosts:          files dns myhostname mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

It gives DNS server results priority over avahi.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 0):

`nslookup` is part of `dnsutils` so you need to install that with:

```
sudo apt install dnsutils
```

First test:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ nslookup lanhost.local
Server:         10.25.2.65
Address:        10.25.2.65#53

Name:   lanhost.local
Address: 10.25.2.67

pi@raspberry:~ $ ping lanhost.local
ping: unknown host lanhost.local
```

So `nslookup` works, but `ping` doesn't. As [sozkara](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/users/81140/sozkara) mentiones. We need to edit `/etc/nsswitch.conf`.

```
sudo nano /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

Change this line

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns
```

so it looks like this

```
hosts:          files dns myhostname mymachines mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return]
```

Second Test:

```
pi@raspberry:~ $ ping lanhost.local
PING lanhost.local (10.25.2.67) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lanhost.local (10.25.2.67): icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=1.69 ms
64 bytes from lanhost.local (10.25.2.67): icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.783 ms
64 bytes from lanhost.local (10.25.2.67): icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.558 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you also tagged the raspberrypi zero:
Windows does not implement mDNS properly. For that you need a servoce like Bonjour. This allows devices to register properly on .local

See here for further information https://learn.adafruit.com/bonjour-zeroconf-networking-for-windows-and-linux

(might also hrlp with other